Proof of Existence of Partitions of unity in "Introduction to Topological manifolds"
I have a question reading the proof of Existence of Partitions of Unity in "Introduction to Topological manifolds" 2nd by John M.Lee. (p.114-115)
The statement is:
Theorem 4.85 Let X be a paracompact Hausdorff space. If $\mathcal{U}$ is any indexed open cover of X, then there is a partition of unity subordinated to $\mathcal{U}$.
The proof starts by obtaining locally finite open covers $\mathcal{V}=(V_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ and $\mathcal{W}=(W_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ where the index set $A$ is same as $\mathcal{U}$ applying Lemma 4.84 twice.
Lemma 4.84 is: Suppose X is a paracompact Hausdorff space. If  $\mathcal{U}=(U_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ is an indexed open cover of X, then $\mathcal{U}$ admits a locally finite open refinement $\mathcal{V}=(V_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ indexed by the same set, such that $\bar{\mathcal{V}_\alpha}\subseteq U_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.
I think the lemma only gurantee the existence of "locally finite open "refinement", but necessarily a cover. How can I know that they are open cover?

A refinement of a cover is a cover, and they explicitly say "open" in 4.84.

@SassatelliGiulio I didn't know that. Could you explain why it is true?

@SassatelliGiulio Oh, is it by definition? The definition of a refinement of a "cover" contains that it must be a cover?

I believe yes, but maybe the book uses another one.

@SassatelliGiulio Thank you. It was just a trivial thing. I missed that adjective..

Quote from p.109 of Lee's book:

Given a cover $\mathscr A$ of $X$, another cover $\mathscr B$ is called a refinement of  $\mathscr A$ if for each $B \in \mathscr B$ there exists some $A \in \mathscr A$ such that $B \subseteq A$. It is an open refinement if
each $B \in \mathscr B$ is an open subset of $X$.

That is, an open refinement is an open cover by definition.
Have a look into the proof of Lemma 4.84 to see that Lee's $\mathscr V$ is indeed a cover of $X$.
